# "Sticky" headers on a table with horizontal scroll... completely impossible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

After researching this for the last few hours, I'm beginning to think this is impossible, even on the most up-to-date browsers:

HTML `table` element with a horizontal scroll, with a "sticky" `thead` on the top, as part of a surrounding web page that scrolls vertically.

Here's my attempt:

```css
#a {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  position:sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#b {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  some content
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="test">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>sticky header</th>
        <th>sticky header</th>
        <th>sticky header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="b">
  some more content
</div>
```

(There's also [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skeets23/kme6ndpt/1/), so you can mess with the code)

The way it currently is, the "position: sticky" doesn't work when the `#wrapper` is `overflow-x: scroll`. If you remove the overflow-x rule, it works, but then of course the table expands the width of the entire page (which is definitely not cool)

I know making the table the "scrolling" element would fix the issue, but that's not desirable either (I only want the web page body to be scrollable vertically).

I've tried to come up with alternate CSS solutions, and even Javascript solutions, but I can't think of a solution that would ultimately work. Is this actually impossible?

While I'd prefer a `css` solution, I'm open to a javascript solution at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trickytree22/h4trbk60/20/) with a working example. You could even get rid of some of the javascript by declaring width/height beforehand.

Added some ids to your original example

```
<div id="a">
  some content
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="test">
    <thead id="sticky">
      <tr id="headerRow">
        <th>sticky header</th>
        <th>sticky header</th>
        <th>sticky header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="b">
  some more content
</div>
```

Below is the javascript

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute addSticky 
window.onscroll = function() {addSticky()};
document.getElementById("wrapper").onscroll = function(){addSticky()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("sticky");

// Get the offset position
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Get bottom offset
var bottomOffset = document.getElementById("test").offsetHeight+100;


// Set the width of the row and columns by placing them in an array and looping said array
var headerRow = document.getElementById("headerRow");
header.style.width = headerRow.offsetWidth+"px";
var headerKids = headerRow.children;
for (var i=0; i<headerKids.length; i++){
  headerKids[i].style.width=headerKids[i].offsetWidth+"px";
}

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function addSticky() {
  if (this.scrollY > 100 && this.scrollY < bottomOffset ) {
    xScroll = document.getElementById("wrapper").scrollLeft;
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    header.style.left = "-"+xScroll+"px";
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Updates to CSS

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: First answer that hits all the criteria! It looks like it's just missing `document.getElementById("wrapper").onscroll = function(){addSticky()};`. Without this, it breaks when you scroll vertically half way down the table, and then try to scroll horizontally inside the table

Comment: The body in the fiddle also apparently has a 8 px margin, so that would need to be taken into account as well. But since this answer proves it can be done without a 1000+ line library (like the one in my answer), I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm using this solution instead of the library I found previously, since it turns out that library didn't support Safari. To make it smoother and to maintain the table structure, I cloned the header upon initialization, and have it set to `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`. Then, when the sticky header switches to `fixed`, I also show the "hidden" header.

Comment: Edited the post (and the fiddle) to include the horizontal scroll, also cleaned up the code slightly (no need to get headerRow twice).

Comment: Thanks! However it looks like you need to update the fiddle link in this answer to: https://jsfiddle.net/trickytree22/h4trbk60/20/

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the `jquery.floatThead` package **does** do what I'm looking for, I was just missing this setting:

```
$("table").floatThead({
position:"absolute"
});
```

It defaults to "fixed", which doesn't work in this case.

You can see the fixed fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/skeets23/kme6ndpt/7/), working exactly as I needed.

Still, it's kind of ridiculous that I need a javascript package to do a task this simple. If I'm missing something and there's a simpler answer to this basic issue, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked but try to tamper with this table:

https://codepen.io/joelPrz/pen/Gclki

```js
var tee = $('.gridtable thead');
var tw = document.getElementsByClassName('tabWrap')[0];
var cloner = document.getElementsByClassName('tabWrap')[0];
var bd = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
var newTableWrap = document.createElement("div");
var newTable = document.createElement("Table");
var oldTable = document.getElementsByClassName('gridtable')[0];
var childNode = oldTable.childNodes[1];
var wrapW = $(tw).css('width');
var wrapY = $(tw).css('height');
var headHeight = tee.css('height');

//node The node to be cloned.
var dupNode = childNode.cloneNode(true);
newTable.appendChild(dupNode);
newTableWrap.appendChild(newTable);

newTable.classList.add("gridtableT");
newTable.classList.add("gridtable");

$(newTableWrap).css({'width': wrapW, 'overflow':'hidden'});

bd.insertBefore(newTableWrap , tw);
$(oldTable).css('margin-top', ('-' + headHeight) );

$('tr td').filter(":last-child")
  .css('border-right-color', 'transparent');

$('tr:last td').css('border-bottom-color', 'transparent');

$(tw).on('scroll', function(e){
  var newLeft = e.target.scrollLeft;
  $(newTable).css('margin-left', '-' + newLeft + 'px');
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

th, td {
  border-left-color: transparent!important;
}

.last-cell {
  border-right-color: transparent!important;
}

.container {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  outline-offset: 0px;
  width: 800px;
}

.tabWrap {
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 800px;
}

.gridtable {
  color:#333333;
  font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
}

.gridtable th {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding: 8px;
}

.gridtable td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.gridtableT { color: red; }

.gridtableT th { border-top-color: transparent; }

.lastRow td {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

div.tabWrap th {
  border-bottom-color: transparent!important;
  border-top-color: transparent!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="tabWrap">
  <table class="gridtable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Head One</th>
        <th>Head Two</th>
        <th>Head Three</th>
        <th>Head Four</th>
        <th>Head Five</th>
        <th>Head Six</th>
        <th>Head Seven</th>
        <th>Head Eight</th>
        <th>Head Nine</th>
        <th>Head Ten</th>
        <th>Head Eleven</th>
        <th>Head Twelve</th>
        <th>Head Thirteen</th>
        <th>Head Fourteen</th>
        <th>Head Fifteen</th>
        <th>Head Sixteen</th>
        <th>Head Seventeen</th>
        <th>Head Eighteen</th>
        <th>Head Nineteen</th>
        <th class="last-cell" style="width:6%">Head Twenty</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="firstRow">
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three Four Dive</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
        <td>Data Five</td>
        <td>Data Six</td>
        <td>Data Seven</td>
        <td>Data Eight</td>
        <td>Data Nine</td>
        <td>Data Ten</td>
        <td>Data Eleven</td>
        <td>Data Twelve</td>
        <td>Data Thirteen</td>
        <td>Data Fourteen</td>
        <td>Data Fifteen</td>
        <td>Data Sixteen</td>
        <td>Data Seventeen</td>
        <td>Data Eighteen</td>
        <td>Data Nineteen</td>
        <td>Data Twenty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="lastRow">
        <td>Last One</td>
        <td>Last Two</td>
        <td>Last Three</td>
        <td>Last Four</td>
        <td>Last Five</td>
        <td>Last Six</td>
        <td>Last Seven</td>
        <td>Last Eight</td>
        <td>Last Nine</td>
        <td>Last Ten</td>
        <td>Last Eleven</td>
        <td>Last Twelve</td>
        <td>Last Thirteen</td>
        <td>Last Fourteen</td>
        <td>Last Fifteen</td>
        <td>Last Sixteen</td>
        <td>Last Seventeen</td>
        <td>Last Eighteen</td>
        <td>Last Nineteen</td>
        <td>Last Twenty</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

The Header is sticky, but only inside the table, not the page. So maby you can alter it to your Needs.

(Open the Code by link, the Code I copied here, somehow has an error)

Comment: not quite.... quoting from my question: `I know making the table the "scrolling" element would fix the issue, but that's not desirable either (I only want the web page body to be scrollable vertically).`

Comment: So the table should scroll horizontally, and the page scroll vertically. I tried with the code pen you provided, but it breaks the stickiness just like in my fiddle

Comment: What if you make the table size 100%. That way the header shoud stick the same way

Comment: That would either stretch the table (leaving a big empty space) or make the table vertically scrollable (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

If you user `overflow` with anything other then `visible` you must give the element fixed height, otherwise when you scroll the parent the element is ready to stick but the height is unconstrained.

A simple CSS solution is to give `#wrapper` height using the viewport (i.e `vh`)

```
#wrapper {
  height: 30vh;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
#a {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
}

th {
  position:sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#b {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#scroller{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  some content
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="test">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>sticky header</th>
        <th>sticky header</th>
        <th>sticky header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
        <td>long content long content long content long content long content long content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="b">
  some more content
</div>
```

Comment: not quite.... quoting from my question: `I know making the table the "scrolling" element would fix the issue, but that's not desirable either (I only want the web page body to be scrollable vertically).`

Comment: you mean that you want to remove the vertical scroll form the table?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean. The table should be displayed in full... I need the element that scrolls horizontally and the element that scrolls vertically to be different elements

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: sticky` for table is applicable. Please see the below code.

```css
thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
            <th>column 4</th>            
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>Data One</td>
        <td>Data Two</td>
        <td>Data Three</td>
        <td>Data Four</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please refer to https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky where you can check if the feature is usable or not.

Comment: I'm already using `position:sticky`. The problem is that `sticky` completely breaks when the table is scrollable horizontally on a page that scrolls vertically